# sending sms message with vb and modem 3g

Tags: vb.net

Hello guys I'm created a windows form that has a basic function of sending sms message to a phone by using my 3g modem. My modem 3g has load that will be use for texting. I check my device manager and I saw my modem 3g is already connected but Unfortunately, it's not sending sms message to my phone's number. here's my code so far. By the way my portname of device is com4

```
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Dim ports As String() = SerialPort.GetPortNames
            Dim port As String
            For Each port In ports
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(port)
            Next port
            ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            With SerialPort1
                .PortName = ComboBox1.Text
                .BaudRate = 9600
                .Parity = Parity.None
                .StopBits = StopBits.One
                .DataBits = 8
                .Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend
                .DtrEnable = True
                .RtsEnable = True
                .NewLine = vbCrLf
                .Open()
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Try
            If SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
                With SerialPort1
                    .Write("AT" & vbCrLf)
                    .Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)
                    .Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & TextBox1.Text & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
                    .Write(RichTextBox1.Text & Chr(26))
                    MsgBox("Succesfully Send!")
                End With
            Else
                MsgBox("Port not open!")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Do u get any exception ?

Comment: You have an empty Catch block. Any errors that happen will be ignored because of this. In the `Button2_Click` sub, delete the three lines that are `Try` and `Catch ex as exception` and `End Try`. Re run the code and see what errors you get. These try catch blocks are only really only to handle unexpected happenings in working code. You should really write code to allow for everything you can think of, debug all that and make sure it works, and THEN start adding try..catch..end try.